# Can we add hyperlink to report description property in SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services

I want to add a link to my report description.When clicked on the link it shoul;d take me to a document.Is it possible to specify link/url in ssrs report description property?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not a supported feature.

Comment: @user1751845 Sorry this wasn't the answer you were hoping for. Given that it's the only answer, please mark it accordingly. Thanks.